# updating nested array in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

With the given the data model below:

```
{
  "snapshots": [
    {
      "createdAt": "2019-03-15T06:31:04.447Z",
      "entries": [
        {
          "balance": 139763,
          "expiresOn": "3019-03-31T23:59Z"

        },
        {
          "balance": 46961,
          "expiresOn": "3019-03-31T23:59Z"

        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "type": "account"
}
```

I am trying to update the **expiresOn** field in the **entries** array in **snapshots** array, below is the query i tried but doesn't work.

```
UPDATE bucket
SET snapshot.entry.expiresOn = "2020-03-30T23:59Z"
FOR snapshot IN snapshots
  FOR entry IN snapshot.entries
END
WHERE type = "account"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is right query for update the expiresOn field in the entries array in snapshots array. SET snapshot.entry.expiresOn = "2020-03-30T23:59Z" may update wrong place or will not update (due to extra reference of snapshot).

```
UPDATE bucket AS b
SET entry.expiresOn = "2020-03-30T23:59Z"
FOR entry IN snapshot.entries FOR snapshot IN b.snapshots END
WHERE b.type = "account";
```

Comment: Yeah my bad in pasting the answer, did exactly this. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

got it working, was a silly mistake.

The inner array in the json model should be the outer for-loop in the query.

```
UPDATE bucket
SET entry.expiresOn = "2020-03-30T23:59Z"
FOR entry IN snapshot.entries FOR snapshot IN snapshots END
WHERE type = "account"
```